# Duration of Apple Push Notification

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to set the duration you want a push notification you sent to show for 5 or 10 seconds then it's automatically deleted? Or delete it when it hits a certain time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not remove the the notification from the apple screen by setting your own custom time.
You can handle the time and all things in your application.

Because iOS is not allow to remove notification from the device notification screen .

Comment: how do you handle it in your application?

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
use this method.

Comment: Can you remove something from you notification center from that method?